# CouchDB: limit action to logged users

Tags: validation, authentication, couchdb

I'm working with `validate_doc_update` function. I've heard about userCtx, but simply calling `log(userCtx);` helps no way: there's no records in the log.

How determine in validation is current user logged or not and maybe perform some checks to verify against user rights (which may be made by simple fields like `role:editor` in `_users` database)?

Comment: Check out the docs about the [user context object](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/json-structure.html?highlight=userctx#user-context-object) and [validation handlers](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/ddocs.html?highlight=validate_doc_update#validate-document-update-functions), they will give you more context.

Answer (score 0):

The user context is accessible under `req.userCtx`.

A common check of the loggedIn-status is `if (req.userCtx.name !== null)`

The access right roles of a user doc are accessible under `req.userCtx.roles`. The corresponding settings for a doc can be included hard-coded in the `validate_doc_update` function or in the doc itself.